# Are there speed cameras on stretches of the Autobahn with a temporary speed limit?

Tags: germany, driving

Driving on the Autobahn one can often see a *temporary* speed limit:

[image: autobahn speed limit]

Are these limits actually enforced, either through a speed camera or by policemen carrying a radar?

Comment: That's Germany, so yes.

Comment: @mts I've seen lots of people completely ignoring these signs though. I assume those are the locals knowing the limit is "optional".

Comment: Please see my answer. I would disagree with your conclusion, they might know where the controls are or just not care as much (but don't follow their lead, please).

Comment: For checking where speed limits are, and some cameras, check this question - http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22193/are-there-online-maps-showing-the-speed-limit-on-the-german-highways

Comment: @mts We've driven through such speed limits at a slightly faster pace (10-20 over) with no fine issued later on, but that's just one data point.

Comment: @JonathanReez: When you're going faster than 100 km/h, they deduct 5% safety margin for measurement errors anyway (it's 3% if you're slower than 100). So they typically set the camera to at least 20 over, as they don't want to waste limited amount of film (no digital photography for evidence reasons) on people who go 115 and get fined 10€ for driving 104 after the safety margin. In towns (50 allowed) most cameras are set to 60-65.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm that's odd, IIRC in the US there's no margin for measurement errors - speedometers are required to be calibrated so that any error goes over rather than under.

Comment: @Random832 Speedometers *in cars*, yes, same in Germany. The velocity they show may never be too low, but up to 10% + 4 km/h too high. This is a EU regulation. As the accuracy of those changes with the age/diameter of the tire, this is to prevent drivers from blaming the speedometer when they go too fast. The measurement devices used by law enforcement however, are calibrated as exactly as possible and have to be recalibrated regularily; the safety margin is to compensate for possible deviations between recalibrations.

Comment: FYI, the Wall Street Journal has an [article out today](http://www.wsj.com/articles/renting-a-car-in-europe-watch-out-for-speeding-tickets-1465405665) that discusses this generally. (sorry for paywall)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

(Source: I am German, have been driving in Germany for 25+ years, and had, altogether, 3 temporary driving bans of one month each for speeding)

Yes, these things are enforced.

A different answer says `enforced in areas that are urbanised, substandard, accident-prone, or under construction`, this is at least misleading. Those areas are more prone to having any speed limits at all, but if there are any, they are enforced, no matter the area.

Basically there are 3 (possibly 4) ways for enforcing them:

- Stationary radar traps. Yes, we Germans call them traps, even if that's in no way an official designation. These stationary traps are connected to the limit signs, so they adjust to changed limits, immediately. If a speed limit changes, for example, from 120 km/h to 100 km/h, and the radar trap is 2 km behind the sign, you'll have 2-3 minutes before the trap changes. I know of at least one case when someone said he had been taking a break at a parking between sign and trap (there is an official park place there), the court dismissed this, saying he should have noted everyone else slowing down and inferred the new speed limit. One example I've been driving for years is the A8 between Ulm and Stuttgart, there were 6 traps in a 25 km stretch (3 in each direction); there's construction work going on there right now and the traps are (at the moment) removed. Examples of those (these are not Autobahn images, but the devices look the same): [image: this] [image]
- Mobile traps. You won't see a policeman standing next to the road with "carry-on" laser guns, at least not on the Autobahn, for safety reasons. But they have portable devices they place at the side of the road for a few hours. These are typically on stretches that have a fixed speed limit, but there are rumors they fix the automatic signs to a certain speed (while the trap is installed) to avoid issues with syncing the mobile trap. (Some of those signs are automated, for example, the above-mentioned A8 is foggy quite often in fall, they have automated mechanisms to detect fog and set a speed limit). Example picture:
  [image]

In both of these cases, you won't get pulled over, you'll be photographed for evidence purposes and get a ticket later. If you're a tourist and have a rented car, the ticket will go to the car rental company which will deduct it from your credit card.

- Video surveillance cars. (This is what got me once). They just drive behind you for a few km, make a video of you driving, then pull you over as that's the only way to make sure who the driver is when they don't have a picture. They will watch the video with you and give you a lecture about how dangerous was what you did. They will not trust their own speed-indicator; they will send the video to an expert who will determine your speed from a timer that's shown on the video and landmarks, mostly the lane markings. If you're speeding, and some other car behind you seems to "want to give you a race", make sure to decelerate (not brake!) and adhere to the limit, especially if the car behind you has 2 adults sitting in the front row. (For reasons of evidence these cars always have two policemen).
- "Random" police cars. If you're way faster than you should, they will pursue you, but in most cases, you won't get any else than a stern lecture. Happened to me once as well, I was driving 200 in an area that had a 120 limit, late at night, almost no other cars on the road. I noticed I was overtaking a police car right the second I was next to it; they pursued me and pulled me over. They told me they estimated my speed at 190, but as they were not equipped with a calibrated speedometer, they had no evidence, but warned me had I got caught in a radar trap that would have been 3 month without driving license for me. After promising to be more careful they let me go.

### Consequences

More than 40 km/h over the limit (Autobahn and outside towns) or more than 30 km/h will mean a temporary ban of your drivers license. If you're a foreigner, they won't take your license, but you will still be forbidden from driving. Getting yourself caught again will be very expensive and may even give you some time in jail. Same if you get caugt more than 25 km/h over the limit twice in 12 months.

Between 20 and 30/40 over the limit, you'll get in a special database where some points are assigned depending on your speed (you get the same points for, for example, ignoring a red light); if you accumulate too many of them your license get temporarily suspended as well.

Less then 20 over the limit will cost you some money, but in normal cases, no further consequences. So if you're speeding, try to keep it below 20 km/h. Of course, if there is an accident, your speed will be held against you anyway.

The German Ministry of Transport has a [website](http://www.bmvi.de/SharedDocs/DE/Artikel/LA/bussgeldkatalog.html?nn=58450#3) (in German) that lists costs in Euro, database points, and months of license ban. The first table is in towns, the second outside towns. Those are the fines for normal violations by normal cars; they are generally higher for trucks or in circumstances that are especially dangerous (dense fog, railway crossings, ...).

### Warning devices

Devices that warn about radar controls are not permitted. [Relevant law](https://dejure.org/gesetze/StVO/23.html):

> Wer ein Fahrzeug führt, darf ein technisches Gerät nicht betreiben oder betriebsbereit mitführen, das dafür bestimmt ist, Verkehrsüberwachungsmaßnahmen anzuzeigen oder zu stören. Das gilt insbesondere für Geräte zur Störung oder Anzeige von Geschwindigkeitsmessungen (Radarwarn- oder Laserstörgeräte).

In English: Who drives a vehicle must not use, or possess in usable condition, a device that is intended to show or disturb traffic control measures. This is especially the case for devices that disturb or show velocity controls.

("Possess in usable condition" means "ready for use", this does apply to a device on your dashboard that's switched off, it does not apply to a device in it's original package in the trunk. Long ago, possession was banned as well, but as some EU countries do allow those devices, they had to make mere possession legal).

So, a device that actively monitors laser or radar waves and warns you is  forbidden (75€, 4 points in the database mentioned earlier), and authorities will confiscate and destroy the device. A device that *disturbs* measurement will get you in even more trouble. A device that uses GPS to warn you about fixed radar controls is a bit of a grey area. If that is the only purpse of the device, it'll get confiscated as well. If your navigation device has a "point of interest" database listing radar controls, or you use a smartphone app, you'll typically get the fine, but keep the device. TomTom's Website claims "POI Software is allowed, but there's no case law yet", Navigon says "Some contries allow this, others don't, you have to get informed about the law in your country yourself". More information (in German): http://www.heise.de/autos/artikel/Blitzerwarner-im-Navi-Erlaubt-oder-nicht-1631522.html

As mere possession is legal, coyote sells in Germany as well; their [website](https://www.meincoyote.de/de/faqs/faqs-coyote-fahrassistent.html#13) says the same thing about "your duty to comply with the law, not ours":

> Es liegt jedoch in der Verantwortung des Nutzers, sich vor Fahrtantritt über die jeweils geltenden Regelungen im entsprechenden Land selbst zu informieren.

Comment: Could you elaborate on ""artifically" switched the signs to a certain speed to make the mobile trap work as well"? Are you saying speed limits are lowered just to receive extra revenue from speed fines?

Comment: Or are you saying that mobile speed cameras are connected to the speed limit signs?

Comment: Caught for speeding three times with a driving ban. Fits my answer perfectly, although they seem to contradict each other ;)

Comment: Officially, speed limits are never placed to collect fines, it's always to improve road safety. Some Germans believe this is true, other's don't, and while i have my opinion, i don't have hard evidence either way. They won't set limits that are completely unresonable, but when, on a rainy day, the automatism keeps switching between 120 and 100, they might fix the signs to 100 when operating a mobile trap, because the mobile things don't have the ability to automatically adjust to what the sign says.

Comment: @Jan: Well, 3 times, but in almost 30 years, and the last time was quite a while ago. Some personality traits *do* change when you get older ;)

Comment: Re completely unreasonable: I was once driving from Munich airport to Großhadern along the A92, A99 and A96. It was a clear, sunny day in early spring, temperatures double-digit the entire day. Part of the leg (can’t remember whether it was A92 or A99) where there were no tunnels or anything had these temporary signs and they kept showing 120 for really no apparant reason. That really pissed me off ;)

Comment: @Jan It's even worse in other countries. They have a 120 limit all year long!

Comment: @Jan: Close to big cities, these speed limits are often put up for noise reduction/emission reduction reasons. Especially on clear, sunny days (mostly summer, not spring though) ozone is a problem in cities that gets addressed by traffic restrictions.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm - thanks a million for this outstanding information.  Awesome.  mfg

Comment: hey @GuntramBlohm, are we allowed to have "coyote" type devices in .de?  Do people use them anyway, does the system exist there?  cheers

Comment: @Jan: Often those temporary limits are also set to prevent traffic jams, i.e. based on road congestion.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Added a paragraph about coyote and similar devices.

Comment: Just about the warning: The position of mobile speed cameras is often listed in the newspaper in advance, and also local radio stations notify you where the camera actually is. That's perfectly legal. The argumentation is that they don't give the precise position (though every local knows them) and they don't warn you explicitly when you are near the cam...

Comment: @GuntramBlohm fascinating, got it.  It sounds like the fact is, some if not many, cars probably have a Coyote on their dashboard in .de?

Comment: @JoeBlow: I personally don't know anybody who has such a device, and i don't think many people do. As the legality of them is at least questionable, and as it's much easier for a police officer to identify a coyote as being a device explicitly used for circumventing speed controls than checking if a smartphone or a navigation aid has an "addon", people will rather use the latter. Most people, though, don't use either, and just stay within the "10-20 km/h over what's permitted" range that's relatively safe.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** I've rewritten my answer, especially to address the question about the variable speed limit.

### The signs

These signs can show different speed limits, which is for example used as flow control. If there's much traffic or even a jam ahead, speed limit is reduced.

In general, these signs are as valid as their normal, printed counterpart.

### Enforcement

Speed limits are of course enforced in Germany, though the fines are relatively low compared to other countries.

### Stationary cameras

@Guntram Blohm has already shown some of them. But especially on the Autobahn, I know this ones on the A3 near Limburg:

[image]

The speed limits signs were extraordinary large, and repeated three times or so. If you don't care, the last sign will make a photo ;-)

There's also a [web site](http://www.meine-auto.info/ratgeber/autobahn-info/radarfallen.html) listing all stationary speed cameras on the Autobahn

### Stationary cameras on tracks with various speed limits

According to the site posted above, there are indeed some stationary speed cams, which adapt to the variable speed limit. The right column states the threshold for the trigger:

[image]

### Non-stationary speed cameras

Of course, we have mobile cameras. They can be stand-alone devices, sometimes built into cars parking at the side of the street, or even trash bins (!)

### Police

A laser speed gun is often used by the police, but of course not on the autobahn. But they have civil cars (i.e. no police cars) with a video recording system, which is also calibrated for precise speed measurements. This videos are also conclusive when you go to court.

[image]

We don't have many of those cars, and they are more or less looking for the really bad guys, which drive waaay to fast or show other bad driving habits.

### Special cameras

Just for completeness, and because of interest:

The Autobahn A1 crosses the Rhine in Leverkusen, and it turned out a few years ago, that the bridge is very ramshackle, and even can't be repaired. A new bridge will be build, but it's still in the planning phase. The existing bridge has a speed limit of 60km/h and is closed for vehicles of more than 3500kg. But since the detour is very long, many trucks ignored this. The bridge now has two cameras in each direction, one for speed, and one for weight...

Ah, and there are some pilot projects for cameras measuring the distance between vehicles on the autobahn, because it is often way too low.

### Note:

Police will always stop and fine you directly. Any kind of speed camera is operated by the city, district or state, and you'll receive a letter from them, not the police.

Comment: It's not the first time I hear about speed cameras on board a car (not only in Germany) but I am yet to witness one or hear about anybody getting caught that way and I have to wonder how effective those are and/or how many of these are actually operational. To an extent, I feel this is more about show than anything else and I am not sure knowing that fully addresses the question. Regular mobile speed cameras do not seem very practical in this scenario either: We are not talking about roadworks area or anything like that but about limits changing from one minute to the next.

Comment: PS: I did not downvote your answer however!

Comment: @Relaxed British police cars carry video cameras and are capable of measuring the speed of other vehicles on the road. You can see this in any one of the multiple TV shows that follow traffic patrol cops. I'd be surprised if the German police didn't have the same technology.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Of course, I have seen such shows about France or Germany too… but also one TV show airing complaints about how poorly they worked in practice and how little they were actually used. And even the more upbeats reports only ever mentioned a handful such cars for the whole country. And I also remember reading some magazine article treating this as news some 15-20 years ago and then the same thing again as the French police recently bought a couple of new cars. Meanwhile, I have never seen any stats or heard about anybody getting caught that way (as anecdotal as that is, obviously).

Comment: That's precisely why I am speculating those are mostly for show/demonstration purposes at this stage or perhaps a case of some clever vendor overselling very expensive yet not very useful technology and a good answer would offer something more than “They exist, I have seen them on TV”.

Comment: @Relaxed, they are most definitely not "for show" in the UK. I've been caught by them a couple of times and fined, not just warned. The first time was about 25 years ago, so they aren't exactly new technology. AFAIK most UK police cars have the equipment fitted, together with other stuff like automatic number plate recognition to catch cars being driven without valid registration, insurance or safety test certificates red-handed (and cars reported as stolen, of course). Note, the UK has national databases for those things - we don't use physical "annual licences" displayed on the car any more.

Comment: @Relaxed, Also, modern laser speed guns have a maximum range of up to **one mile** (1.6km) - much further than the old radar systems.There is no problem isolating a single vehicle from other traffic on the road at that range with a laser device (and if you are speeding you won't be "hidden in the middle of line of vehicles" unless they are *all* speeding).

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, these temporary speed limit signs are equally valid as permanent signs are. As such, when speeding and getting caught you face the same consequences as if there had been a fixed sign on the roadside.

However, I disagree with the other answers somewhat. Germany is *very* lenient when it comes to enforcing speed limits. It is not unheard of for speeding in an urban 30 km/h zone to only be enforced at speeds of 40 km/h onwards. (that’s over 30 % more!) I have heard various rules of thumb as to which faster speed is acceptable, and most boil down to a formula of:

> 10 % + 3 km/h, rounded up to the nearest multiple of ten.

Attempt that kind of speeding in other countries and you are in for big fines.

Another point is that — despite what many people perceive — speeding fines in Germany are rather low when compared to other European countries. If you are caught driving 140 km/h (measurement tolerances already deducted) on the motorway on a stretch where 120 km/h are allowed, your fine is merely 30 €.

The density of speed cameras varies greatly depending on the *Bundesland* you are in. Baden-Württemberg is on top of the ladder with over 1100 fixed cameras while Bavaria, despite being the largest state, only has 85. ([Numbers from early 2015](http://www.abendzeitung-muenchen.de/inhalt.wenig-geschwindigkeitskontrollen-nur-85-blitzer-standorte-raser-mekka-bayern.6c302c56-d6db-42fe-9950-295e4d03f921.html)) The police ‘have better things to do’ in many areas rather than stand around and enforce speed limits. So altogether, there is a strong lenience towards speed limit enforcing.

This means, if the temporary speed limit is 120 km/h, most drivers will drive at 130 to 140 km/h, and even if the police do measure, this is unlikely to get enforced. Go with the flow and typically nothing will happen. If enforcement is present, they will be on the lookout for the blatant speeding outliers.

Comment: Note that measurements have been outsourced to private companies in some cases and in some of those some cases are used to make big money. Besides that +1

Comment: @mts True that. Although as far as I know that only happened for urban speed enforcement. (If you can give me evidence that that happens on country roads and motorways, I would be very happy =D.)

Comment: Only two sentences actually address the question without given an answer and your link is in German. Pointing out that enforcement can start from higher speeds than the official limit is useful but this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @sweber these signs are valid and this being Germany, yes the limits will be enforced.

I've been passing through one such stretch fairly frequently and while I have never seen mobile radars there, I have been warned of popular spots and have frequently heard the warnings on the radio. Also the vast majority of drivers really sticks to the speed limit (with German precision) in that area.

The system of temporary traffic controls is used for controlling the flow of traffic around peak hours (in theory, in reality always), alleviating traffic jams and avoiding accidents (i.e. slowing down traffic before hitting a jam / construction site / accident site).
In the aforementioned section there are cameras on poles throughout for monitoring traffic and most people do stick to the limits (within 10km/h at least), so I would be very surprised if there were no controls at all. In fact, if not knowing the place you should always expect mobile controls and drive within 10km/h of the limit). Police cars might try to catch you if you really exceed the limits as mentioned by @sweber (but personally I feel 30km/h over the limit might only trigger them on a bad day).

Finally, [here is a map with permanent speed controls](http://map.scdb.info/speedcameramap/ll/46.498392,19.335938/z/4). Mobile ones are also announced on the radio (on most stations, in German, every full and half hour after the news) and there exist apps.

Comment: I am not sure we are talking about the same type of temporary limits. On the A2 for example, it's not only at well-defined peak hours around urban areas, you have limits that are apparently set semi-automatically on the whole length of the motorway, going on and off from one section to the next based on (presumably) measures of rain or traffic. It's difficult to see how regular mobile cameras can cope with this.

Comment: @Relaxed the one I talk about is as described in the Q and likely as the one you refer to. I would be surprised if the police/company carrying out the speed control were not in contact in some way with the central setting the limits, but I have no reference for that at the moment.

Comment: I, for one, wouldn't be too surprised if it wasn't the case. It's not completely trivial to do.

Comment: @Relaxed: Especially in places where they have fixed radar controls, they are connected to the signs, resp. the control centre. The A8 between Ulm and Stuttgart had sensors that detected fog and controlled signs *and* radar controls for a long time; iirc dating back to before 2000.