# Where in the EU can I rent and drive a sports car on a professional racing track?

Tags: europe, driving, where-on-earth

Many commentators have suggested that [speed driving on the Autobahn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69711/what-is-the-longest-stretch-of-the-autobahn-that-is-guaranteed-to-have-no-speed) is not as fun as it sounds and I should consider going for a racing track instead. Where in the EU (preferably Central Europe) can I do so?

Since regular rental companies are unlikely to agree to let their cars go on a racing track, only locations with an attached rental facility will be acceptable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57527/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-where-in-the-eu-can-i-rent-and-drive-a-sp).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a reasonable number of car hire places which specialise in this kind of thing: essentially they rent you a car with track day insurance, and access to a track. Much like the "bring your own car" track days, but they provide the car too.

- http://www.bookatrack.com/ (UK site but covers other tracks in Europe)
- http://www.rsrnurburg.com/product/track-days

Prices vary from around €200 to €8,000+ depending on the car you wish to hire and circuit

Donington Park is about the cheapest circuit I know of. Circuits that host/have historically hosted Formula 1 events (Spa/Monza/Silverstone etc) tend to be more expensive, along with the Nurburgring and Le Mans.

The Nurburgring is fairly cheap itself, but car hire there tends to be quite expensive.

Comment: Geek fact, Donnington did host F1 in 1993, with the famous Senna overtake down the outside of the Craner curves in the drizzle on slicks! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_European_Grand_Prix

Comment: A good point :) completely forgot about that... Although it's really not known as an F1 circuit, what with Silverstone and Brands Hatch

Comment: Nurburgring is not really a great place for beginners.  The track is long so you won't learn the correct lines and get the most out of it in one sitting.

Comment: @JamesRyan I agree that it is really bad idea for beginners to drive through "Green hell". There were good reasons why to discontinue the F1 races there... But without the beginers, there wont't be such videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vm7ToxPuQk

Answer (score 7):

Just off the top of my head check out [Nürburgring](http://www.nuerburgring.de/en/home.html), which lets you [drive your own](http://www.nuerburgring.de/en/drives-fun/drives/touristenfahrten.html), [rent a car](http://www.nuerburgring.de/en/drives-fun/drives/car-rentals.html), [train](http://www.nuerburgring.de/en/drives-fun/drives/driver-trainings.html), etc...

So have fun.

P.S. From what I also been told owners may be able to test drive on [Ferrari test track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiorano_Circuit) but this is hearsay.

Comment: right here: http://www.nuerburgring.de/en/drives-fun/drives/car-rentals.html +1

Comment: Note that Nürburg (aka Nuerburg) is about 400km from Nurnberg (aka Nuremberg). The former is famous for its race track; the latter, unfortunately, for its connections with the Nazi regime.  (Answer edited.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Being a Bavarian I am generally skeptical when it comes to praising Nuremberg, but you are doing it unjustice. Nuremburg is famous for its *Lebkuchen* and bratwurst, too ;)

Comment: @David Richerby: It's Nürnberg (the town with the Lebkuchen and the Nazi associations) in German, not Nurnberg. Though the warning is certainly warranted.

Comment: @DavidRicherby So is Munich, Berlin, and quite a few other places.  Doesn't make their history and other accomplishments any less.

Comment: @Karlson My use of the word "unfortunately" was supposed to make it clear that I wasn't attempting to diminish Nürnberg but merely to distinguish it from Nürburg, the place you were actually talking about.

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, track day organisers include [MSV](http://www.msvtrackdays.com/car.aspx) who will rent you an [Ariel Atom](http://www.msvtrackdays.com/car/products/atom-how-fast.aspx), among other cars.

They run track days at the following circuits:

- Brands Hatch
- Oulton Park
- Cadwell Park
- Snetterton
- Bedford Autodrome

Answer (score 1):

A little circuit in France (near Germany): 
[anneau du rhin (Rheinring)](http://www.rheinring.com/stages-de-pilotage/)

Prices are in between 150 and 1000 euro. Depence on the vehicle and duration.