# Are there statistics of the real speed (and accidents) of cars in German autobahns?

Tags: driving

Many highways in Germany (autobahns) do not to have speed limit.

The Wikipedia says:

> In 2015 70.4% of the autobahn network had only the advisory speed
>   limit (130 km/h), 6.2% had temporary speed limits due to weather or
>   traffic conditions, and 23.4% had permanent speed limits. 
>   Measurements from the German State of Brandemburg in 2006 showed average speeds of
>   142 km/h on a 6-lane section of autobahn in free-flowing
>   conditions.

I would like to know not just the the legal maximum but also find some statistics about the real speed people drive on the Autobahn, but I haven't been able to get it.
- distribution of measured speed of cars on the autobahn. 
- statistics of the number of accidents and deceased as a function of the speed.

I've just found very old data saying the average speed in 1992 was 120.4km/h and the 85th percentile 148.2km/h. And in 2006 in 6 lanes areas the average was 141.8km/h.

What percentage of cars exceed 200 km/h?

Comment: I wish lawmakers in other countries used those statistics to likewise increase the speed limits on their highways...

Comment: @JonathanReez higher speeds aren't so good when it comes to emissions though, IIUC?

Comment: @JonathanReez I suspect that removing the motorway speed limit in the UK could create huge problems. With some motorists assuming they can go as fast as they can even when it is not safe, some motorists not seeing any reason to stay out of the fast lane when going 70mph, and some motorists being blissfully unaware that other drivers could now be significantly faster than themselves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travelling.

Comment: *What percentage of cars exceed 200 km/h?* From own observation, less than 5%. You need more than 100kW for that, and most cars are just below.

Comment: https://www.dvr.de/unfallstatistik/de/

Comment: https://www.dvr.de/unfallstatistik/de/autobahnen/

Comment: There's a [study in Brandenburg](https://mil.brandenburg.de/media_fast/4055/studie_tempolimit.pdf) where they looked at what happened to the number of accidents after establishing a speed limit on a previously unlimited stretch of road. I wrote an [answer summarising it on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/20011/16700) for another question. (Summary: the rates of accidents went down by 25% or so).

Comment: [Dataset on the real speed of cars in German autobahns](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/20695/1652)